# Missing context for method declaration in IOS 8 for MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6, mwphotobrowser

I am having problems with MWPhoto library after moving to IOS 8 and XCODE 6. The error occurs in PSTCollectionView class. I am wondering why it returns me `Missing context for method declaration` error. Below you can find the code and image for error.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) {
        NSString *selString = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
        if ([selString hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
            SEL cleanedSelector = NSSelectorFromString([selString substringFromIndex:1]);
            signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:cleanedSelector];
        }
    }
    return signature;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    NSString *selString = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
    if ([selString hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
        SEL cleanedSelector = NSSelectorFromString([selString substringFromIndex:1]);
        if ([self respondsToSelector:cleanedSelector]) {
            invocation.selector = cleanedSelector;
            [invocation invokeWithTarget:self];
        }
    }else {
        [super forwardInvocation:invocation];
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i update PSTCollectionView from github and now works fine
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView